Error: [Slate] initialValue is invalid! Expected a list of elements but got: undefined in React Slate Editor
I'm encountering an issue with my React Slate editor where I receive the following error:
Uncaught Error: [Slate] initialValue is invalid! Expected a list of elements but got: undefined


This error occurs after the component renders multiple times. Below is my current implementation:
import React, { useState, useCallback, useMemo, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { Slate, Editable, withReact } from 'slate-react';
import { createEditor, Transforms, Text, Editor } from 'slate';
import { withHistory } from 'slate-history';
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import showdown from 'showdown';
import htmlToPdfmake from 'html-to-pdfmake';
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

const initialValue = [
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    children: [{ text: 'Start typing your document...' }],
  },
];

const initialState = {
  document: { title: '', content: initialValue },
  loading: true,
  error: null,
};

function documentReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DOCUMENT':
      return { ...state, document: action.payload, loading: false, error: null };
    case 'SET_LOADING':
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload, error: null };
    case 'SET_ERROR':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'UPDATE_TITLE':
      return { ...state, document: { ...state.document, title: action.payload } };
    case 'UPDATE_CONTENT':
      return { ...state, document: { ...state.document, content: action.payload } };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
}

const DocumentEditor = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(documentReducer, initialState);
  const auth = getAuth();
  const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), []);

  const fetchDocument = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_LOADING', payload: true });
    try {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      if (user && id) {
        const token = await user.getIdToken();
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/documents/${id}`, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        });
        const fetchedDocument = response.data;
        const content = fetchedDocument.content ? JSON.parse(fetchedDocument.content) : initialValue;
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DOCUMENT', payload: { ...fetchedDocument, content } });
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_DOCUMENT', payload: { title: '', content: initialValue } });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching document:', error);
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_ERROR', payload: 'Error fetching document' });
    }
  }, [id, auth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDocument();
  }, [fetchDocument]);

  const handleSave = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      if (user) {
        const token = await user.getIdToken();
        const updatedDocument = { ...state.document, content: JSON.stringify(state.document.content) };
        if (id) {
          await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/documents/${id}`, updatedDocument, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          });
        } else {
          await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/documents', updatedDocument, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          });
        }
        navigate('/documents');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving document:', error);
    }
  }, [state.document, id, auth, navigate]);

  const handleExportMarkdown = () => {
    const converter = new showdown.Converter();
    const markdown = state.document.content.map(node => Editor.string(editor, node)).join('\n');
    const blob = new Blob([markdown], { type: 'text/markdown;charset=utf-8' });
    saveAs(blob, `${state.document.title || 'document'}.md`);
  };

  const handleExportPDF = () => {
    const converter = new showdown.Converter();
    const html = state.document.content.map(node => Editor.string(editor, node)).join('\n');
    const htmlContent = converter.makeHtml(html);
    const pdfContent = htmlToPdfmake(htmlContent);
    const documentDefinition = { content: pdfContent };
    pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).download(`${state.document.title || 'document'}.pdf`);
  };

  const renderElement = useCallback((props) => {
    switch (props.element.type) {
      case 'heading-one':
        return <h1 {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</h1>;
      case 'heading-two':
        return <h2 {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</h2>;
      case 'block-quote':
        return <blockquote {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</blockquote>;
      case 'bulleted-list':
        return <ul {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</ul>;
      case 'numbered-list':
        return <ol {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</ol>;
      case 'list-item':
        return <li {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</li>;
      case 'code':
        return (
          <pre {...props.attributes}>
            <code>{props.children}</code>
          </pre>
        );
      default:
        return <p {...props.attributes}>{props.children}</p>;
    }
  }, []);

  const renderLeaf = useCallback((props) => {
    return (
      <span
        {...props.attributes}
        style={{ fontWeight: props.leaf.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal', fontStyle: props.leaf.italic ? 'italic' : 'normal' }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }, []);

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
      return;
    }

    switch (event.key) {
      case 'b': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { bold: true },
          { match: (n) => Text.isText(n), split: true }
        );
        break;
      }

      case 'i': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { italic: true },
          { match: (n) => Text.isText(n), split: true }
        );
        break;
      }

      case '1': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'heading-one' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      case '2': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'heading-two' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      case 'q': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'block-quote' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      case 'l': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'bulleted-list' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      case 'o': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'numbered-list' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      case 'k': {
        event.preventDefault();
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: 'code' },
          { match: (n) => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        );
        break;
      }

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  if (state.loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (state.error) {
    return <div>Error: {state.error}</div>;
  }

  if (!state.document.content) {
    return <div>Error: Content not loaded correctly</div>;
  }

  console.log('Valid content:', state.document.content);
  console.log('Rendered content:', state.document.content);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
        <Col md={8}>
          <h2>{id ? 'Edit Document' : 'Create Document'}</h2>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formTitle">
              <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter title"
                name="title"
                value={state.document.title}
                onChange={(e) => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_TITLE', payload: e.target.value })}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="formContent" className="mt-3">
              <Form.Label>Content</Form.Label>
              <Slate editor={editor} value={state.document.content} onChange={(value) => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CONTENT', payload: value })}>
                <Editable
                  renderElement={renderElement}
                  renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
                  placeholder="Enter some text..."
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                  spellCheck
                  autoFocus
                />
              </Slate>
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSave} className="mt-3">
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleExportMarkdown} className="mt-3 ms-2">
              Export as Markdown
            </Button>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleExportPDF} className="mt-3 ms-2">
              Export as PDF
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default DocumentEditor;


Error Description
Context:
I'm building a document editor using React and Slate, which includes functionalities to load, edit, and export documents.
Problem: After several renders of the component, I get the error Uncaught Error: [Slate] initialValue is invalid! Expected a list of elements but got: undefined.
What I've Tried:
Ensured initialValue is correctly initialized.
Used useReducer for state management.
Added checks to ensure initialValue is not undefined.
Questions:
Why does the error appear after several renders?
How can I ensure initialValue is always correctly initialized and passed to Slate without triggering this error?
Environment:
Slate: 0.67.0
React: 17.0.2
Other Libraries: react-bootstrap, axios, firebase/auth, file-saver, showdown, html-to-pdfmake, pdfmake


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looking in your code you have added
<Slate editor={editor} value={state.document.content} />

I believe it should be
<Slate editor={editor} initialValue={state.document.content} />

